# Making a dialog box appear at the end of an Android game

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So I am currently developing an Android game for a school project, and there is no ending to the game, it just goes on forever. I want to make it a time dependent game where if the player survives a certain amount of time, the game ends and says "Congratulations" and shows a dialog box with a button that once pressed, closes out the game. I know about the AlertDialog.Builder class and I saw somewhere that an activity can be closed by a finish() method, so anyone that can elaborate how to implement this in my game class would be very helpful, all efforts so far have just made the game crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Runnable run = new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
             displayDialog();
     }
};
this.runOnUiThread(run);


private void displayDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(ProvaActivity.this).setPositiveButton("finish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }).show();

}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to just switch to a new class from the GameView class once a certain condition has been met? and in that new class just make my dialog box?

Comment: Im pretty sure there is a way to do what you need, but without the code it is really difficult to know exactly what are you doing and why it is crashing, what @broody sais makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're crashing is probably because you're trying to trigger UI events from another thread. You'll need to implement a Handler to ferry messages from your game thread to the UI. Implement a Handler in your activity class, pass this handler to your game thread and when your game comes to an end do a handler.sendEmptyMessage(GAME_END). In your Handler function do a switch on "msg" to determine what message was received (GAME_END, QUIT, etc)  and you can call your AlertDialog here.